# Need to grep file with specific extension and move to another folder

Tags: bash, grep

I want to write a `bash` command that `grep`s all `*.txt` file with a pattern in current folder to another folder. Should I use `find` or `for` loop? I tried using `find` but it seems to complicate things.

**Edit**: I want to copy files with a specific pattern to a different folder. For example:

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

all have the word "foo" in them. I want grep to remove "foo" and send it to a different folder with the same name. I don't want to change the original file in any way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give some example of the content you wish to find, what information you're trying to use from that output in .. futher work in another directory? .. and how you tried to solve your problem using `find(1)` in the first place?

Comment: Seems like the question is still missing a verb in this phrase "in current folder to another folder." Are we identifying files to mv or cp, or similar?

Comment: I don't want to change the original file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `for` would probably be a lot easier for this than `find`. Something like this:

```
otherdir='your_other_directory'
for file in *.txt; do
    grep -q 'foo' $file && grep -v 'foo' < $file > $otherdir/$file
done
```

If your `grep` doesn't understand `-q` then:

```
otherdir='your_other_directory'
for file in *.txt; do
    grep 'foo' $file > /dev/null && grep -v 'foo' < $file > $otherdir/$file
done
```

In any case, `grep` returns a true value to the shell if it finds a match and the `X && Y` construct executes the `Y` command if `X` returns a true value.

**UPDATE**: The above solution assumes (as noted by Johnsyweb) that you want to remove any **lines** that contain "foo". If you just want to remove "foo" without removing whole lines, then `sed` is your friend:

```
otherdir='your_other_directory'
for file in *.txt; do
    grep -q 'foo' $file && sed 's/foo//g' < $file > $otherdir/$file
done
```

Or:

```
otherdir='your_other_directory'
for file in *.txt; do
    grep 'foo' $file > /dev/null && sed 's/foo//g' < $file > $otherdir/$file
done
```

Comment: `grep -v 'foo' < ${file}` will strip all lines containing 'foo' from ${file}. This *may* be what is required, it's very hard to tell from the question as posed. Alternatively, `sed -e 's/foo//g'` might be more apt.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: The question is rather ambiguous on that point and it looks like John Kugelman made the same choice I did (this is Unix, you're supposed to get burned if you're not careful :). I've added an update to account for that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with find. (You need the `sh -c` to get the `>` redirection to work.)

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'grep -v foo {} > new/{}' \;
```

Or with a for loop. This will be more robust when handling unusual file names, such as files with spaces.

```
for FILE in *.txt; do
    grep -v foo "$FILE" > "new/$FILE"
done
```

If the files are in some other directory `old` rather than the current directory, use `basename` to strip out the directory:

```
for FILE in old/*.txt; do
    grep -v foo "$FILE" > "new/$(basename "$FILE")"
done
```

Comment: question: why are you looping in old/*.txt? Does that mean find all files with .txt in current directory? Also, why do I need basename? isn't $FILE already in basename?

Comment: I probably made this more generic than you needed. Edited my answer.